# Session Variables Not Setting

Tags: php, arrays

This is the script I wrote trying to set variables for an admin user, this session variables however never set, I can tell this because I tested it using the admin dashboard and it does not let me log in

```
<?php
include "admincred.php";
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
if ($username == NULL or $password == NULL){
    echo "Wrong username or password";
}else{
    if ($username !=$adminloginsystem){
        echo "Wrong Admin Username";
}else{

if ($password !=$pw){
    echo "Wrong Admin Password";
}else{
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "1";
    $_SESSION['username'] = "$username";
        $_SESSION['password'] = "$password";
        $_SESSION['admin'] = "1";
header('Location: test2.php');
}}}
?>
```

Comment: Does your `admincred.php` has `session_start();` on top ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You require a `session_start();` at the top of your code just after `<?php` tag.
And this should go on each page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a session by calling session_start() at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
<?php
session_start();
```